Encrypted Hard Disk
I was using windows, then while installing linux ubuntu as dual-boot on the laptop my disk got encrypted.
When i turn on my laptop it asks for an encryption key,unfortunately i do not know the key and my email address was not  synced to the account.
Is there a way for me to retrieve my data from the disk?

"my email address was not synced to the account" Are you talking about Windows BitLocker encryption?
